# how to get a reference to the activity class inside an actionhandler

Tags: android, android-activity, seekbar

This is my code:

```
     seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){


   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageArray[progress], <<NEED A REFERENCE TO THE ACTIVITY CLASS>>, movieFrame);
   }
    }
```

The problem here is i am unable to get a reference to the activity class the seekBar is inside. Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: `YourClass.this` ? EDIT: you should add your complete class code

Comment: @RC : nope tried that..didnt work !

Comment: @ahsan.. why dont you post full code then.. your question is not that clear...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should do it, if i have got your question right..

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){


       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageArray[progress], <<NEED A REFERENCE TO THE ACTIVITY CLASS>>, movieFrame);

    Activity a = YourActivityname.this;
       }
        }
```

if nothing is working out, then create a instance variable of type Activity and initialise it in Activity's onCreate method, something like below.

```
Class A extends Activity{

private Activity instance;
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

instance = A.this;
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use:

`MyActivity.this`

Comment: I think this is a way better solution than accepted one. Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of passing reference.

this.getParent()